# Netsuite approval checkbox on a custom reminder?

Tags: netsuite

I have a custom transaction record with an approval workflow set up in Netsuite.  Users want to be able to use reminders to approve.  Is there a way to get an approval checkbox on the reminder similar to the way the standard transaction approval reminder functions? They want it to be similar to the standard Netsuite "Requisitions to Approve", "Journals to Approve", etc.

I've set up a custom saved search hoping to at least use inline editing to update Approval Status field.  Netsuite doesn't seem to allow inline editing for this transaction type.

Answer (score 1):

Custom record types have a checkbox to allow inline editing

[image]